# Utility for navigating between Spaces (virtual desktops) in the same manner as dragging windows between Spaces, in OS X

Tags: osx, mouse

In OS X, you can drag windows between spaces by positioning the cursor at the left/right edge of the window while dragging.  But you can't navigate between spaces the same way.

I'm looking for a utility that will let me switch to between spaces by positioning the mouse cursor on the left or right edge of the current space, so that navigating between spaces will be consistent with dragging windows between spaces.

A utility called Warp* did this, but it doesn't work on OS X > 10.6.

I'm using OS X 10.10.5.

- http://www.ksuther.com/warp/

Comment: Are you sure you can't do this? On my Mac I can move the mouse to the lower-left, and then click on the space I want to activate in the upper row. I can also add spaces if I move the mouse to the right of the upper row.

Comment: @holroy: Sorry, my title wasn't precise enough.  :(  The body of the question describes what I'm looking for.

Comment: even though it is an alternate procedure, does it work for you to move the mouse to the lower-left (and stay a little while), and the select the space you want in the upper row?

Comment: In Yosemite you can switch spaces by doing a four-finger swipe left or right on a trackpad, or a two finger swipe left or right on a touch surface Apple Magic Mouse.

Comment: @holroy: That's definitely a method to do it.  I personally find hot-corners distracting because you can't add a delay before they are activated.  And I personally believe that finding a utility like I describe will improve consistency in the UI.  P.S. I've updated the question to resolve the ambiguity you pointed out.

Comment: @basil: Thanks for the tip.  I'm new to Macs.  I didn't realize that there were mice that had trackpads on them.  I don't have a Magic Mouse.  I'm using a Logitech M705.  P.S. I've updated the question to resolve the ambiguity you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X Yosemite and other versions have built-in support for gestures to move between full-screen apps, [Mission Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_(OS_X)), and such. But not quite in the specific manner you asked for.

See Apple’s tech note, [Mac Basics: Use Mission Control to switch between apps or spaces](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100).

## Hot Corners

Mac OS X has feature where you can move your mouse to a corner of the screen to trigger certain actions such as displaying [Mission Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_(OS_X)).

In the *System Preferences*, in *Desktop & Screen Saver* > *Screen Saver* (tab) > *Hot Corners* (button), choose from any of the popup menus to set a corner’s action.

[image: screen shot of System Prefences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen Saver > Hot Corners]

## Trackpad

The Trackpad built into MacBooks as well as the [Apple Magic Trackpad](https://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/) can be configured for gestures such as four-finger swipe horizontally to switch between full-screen apps or virtual desktops.

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/images/hero_1.png))</sub>

[image: screen shot of System Preferences panel for Trackpad]

## Mouse

Similarly the touch surface on the [Apple Mighty Mouse](https://www.apple.com/magicmouse/) supports gestures for similar actions such as switch between full-screen apps or virtual desktops with a two-finger swipe horizontally.

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](https://www.apple.com/magicmouse/images/hero_3.jpg))</sub>

[image: screen shot of System Preferences panel for Mouse]